# Redirect with DNS

Tags: php, dns

I need to make a transparent redirect (without the user seeing the address change in the address bar). When the user types example.com he/she should be redirected to 123.123.123.123:9090 (IP:PORT). I cannot use CNAME or A cause it does not accept the PORT. How can I do that? I know that using SRV I can do that but my webserver does not allow it.

I also tried using THE    mod_proxy on Apache to rewrite the request from domain example.com -> 123.123.123.123:9090 however it is absurd cause the user requests the content, the apache requests the content to my IP and after that the response has to go up all way back. I need the user request to reach the webserver directly without proxy.

Comment: Holy inflammatory title batman. Cool your jets.

Comment: Well, DNS doesn't care about ports, only about hostnames.

Comment: You should move this to serverfault it will get better responses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DNS Record with port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245091/dns-record-with-port)

Comment: In mother russia person asking for help insults you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, DNS doesn't care about ports, only about hostnames. Thats why you can access *every* server like `example.com:8080` (will probably fail for 99% of all servers though ;)). So what should happen when I try to request your site via `example.com:8080`? Does port 8080, or 9090 takes precedence?

Long story short: There is no way around a proxy. But easier would be to let it listen on port 80 directly.

Comment: You are wrong. I can use mod_proxy or reverse domain to use IP:PROXY. I can also use SRV DNS Record and it would work perfectly and TRANSPARENT. But this does not work to me due my server confs.

Comment: "You are wrong. I can use mod_proxy or reverse domain to use IP:PROXY. " You know, what "mod_proxy", or "reverse proxy" is? Right: A proxy ;)